# How can I make sure I'm in sync with the UI for style changes based on binding, before modifying the binded property in my C# WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm making an MVVM app that shows a list that grows over time, and marks the new elements not listed when the list was previously updated. I'm trying to make sure I use async methods so the GUI feels responsive and doesn't lock.

I bind to the list item's `ResultDate` and the `LastCheckedTime` in the viewmodel, send those through a converter, style accordingly if ResultDate is newer then LastCheckedTime:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CompareIfNewerConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="ResultDate" />
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}" Path="DataContext.LastCheckedTime"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFF90E0E"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

In my ViewModel, I run an async SQL request, which manually fires `PropertyChanged` for `LastCheckedTime` after results come, so the UI marks the new items accordingly, and *only then* updates `LastCheckedTime`, and doesn't fire the `PropertyChanged` (which is to be fired only next time). However, if I don't add a delay, the styles are done after `LastCheckedTime`. I don't like to depend on timing, because one cannot know whether it will break on somebody else's computer. Here's my hack to fix the problem - this is working on my end:

```
private async Task DoTheFilter(CancellationToken token)
{
    MatchingResultList = await Connectivity.ReturnResultsForPanicViewAsync(token);

    DataGridHeader = (MatchingResultList != null) ? $"Records found: {MatchingResultList.Count}" : "Cancelled.";

    if(MatchingResultList != null && MatchingResultList.Any((r) => r.ResultDate > LastCheckedTime)) System.Media.SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play(); //If any result is newer then the last listing time, warn user with sound

    OnPropertyChanged("LastCheckedTime"); //update visual indicator for new results manually.
    await Task.Delay(133); //allow GUI redraw - Timing based and prone to error?
    LastCheckedTime = DateTime.Now; //update the last checked time only then.
}
```

If I don't add a delay, the styles are applied after the LastTimeChecked is updated in the ViewModel, which means no new item is shown as new. I've seen that even a delay of `1` milliseconds fixes the issue, but I made `133` just to pad it. However, I'd really like to know if there's a fully robust and dependable fix, or whether there's an entirely different approach that I may take.

Edit: I solved the problem using two ways - here's the first:

```
OnPropertyChanged("LastCheckedTime"); //update visual indicator for new results manually.

Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => LastCheckedTime = DateTime.Now), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null); //only update LastCheckedTime after context becomes idle.
```

After I manually notify the ui of the last change, I update the LastCheckedTime only after the context is idle. This seemed to be a more robust way compared to waiting an arbitrary amount of time.

However, the better solution seems to be 'buffering' the `LastCheckedTime` using a second `DateTime`as suggested by Peter Duniho (solution #3). Here's the code...
The command is modified so `LastCheckedTime` is updated first before calling `DoTheFilter()`

```
FilterTestCommand = AsyncCommand.Create((token) => { LastCheckedTime = NewCheckedTime; return DoTheFilter(token); });
```

And I update `NewCheckedTime` inside `DoTheFilter()`. I turned on automatic notifications for the `LastCheckedTime` property change, btw. That said, this may force an unnecessary re-update of the current list before the new list arrives, but it doesn't pose a performance problem. The solution is effective yet simple, that it's somewhat embarrassing for me to not have thought of it, but I did learn some new tricks (dispatcher) that I may make use of elsewhere.

Comment: If I understood your Q, why you dont:      #1 - Run an SQL request.    #2 - Update bound list (whice indirectly updte UI).    #3 - Fire the 'OnPropertyChanged' for LastCheckedTime

Comment: That's what I'm doing, and after I fire the OnPropertyChanged, I re-update the LastTimeChecked value after the UI displays the correct styles, by waiting a small while. However, I need to know if there's any robust way updating LastCheckedTime value, without having to rely on timings.

Comment: It might help to move `LastCheckedTime = DateTime.Now` out of the async method so it isnt updated until after the `DotheFilter` is complete.(awaited)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried it now and it doesn't work, unless of course I do a task delay there too. The update is done before the UI can style based on the old value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd really like to know if there's a fully robust and dependable fix, or whether there's an entirely different approach that I may take

Yes, there is. You are correct to be suspicious of your current approach. It's inherently broken and will eventually produce incorrect results. Your implementation appears to rely on an assumption that WPF will never on its own recheck the `LastCheckedTime` value, and do so *only* when you call the `OnPropertyChanged()` method directly. It's true that it probably won't, but there's no contractual requirement for it to refrain from doing so, and I can easily imagine a scenario where WPF decides it needs to refresh all its bindings for some reason and winds up retrieving the latest value for the `LastCheckedTime` even though you didn't explicitly tell it to.

The only reliable way to do this is to ensure you have reliable input for the visual display in the first place. You can accomplish this in one of at least three ways I can think of:

1. Add a `bool` property to the view model indicating whether the item is new. Before you retrieve the current data, clear the flag on all your items. When you retrieve the data, instead of rewriting the entire set of items, just add the new ones, setting the "is item new" flag on those new items. Instead of multi-binding with a comparison converter, just bind directly to this flag property.
2. As a variation on the previous idea, you can still rewrite the entire set of items, but before you update the `LastCheckedTime` value, go through the list of items and set the flag appropriately according to whether that item's "result" time is more recent than the `LastCheckedTime` value or not. Again, bind to the flag property instead of using the comparison converter.
3. In addition to the "last-checked" time, store also a "previous-checked" time. Use the "previous-checked" time for your comparison in the view. The only thing you'll use the "last-checked" time for is to update the "previous-checked" time each time you retrieve your data. In this case, you can still use the multi-binding with the comparison converter; it's just that you'll compare with the "previous-checked" time value instead of "last-checked".

I note that, based on your description, it sounds as though the `LastCheckedTime` property in your window object's model (i.e. the `DataContext` object) does *not* automatically raise a property-changed notification when the property value is changed. This is in and of itself suspect. If you use one of the techniques above, you will be able to go ahead and implement property-changed notifications on all model properties, in each property setter. And if you do that, you will ensure that all bindings will update immediately when any bound property changes, which will in turn ensure consistent and bug-free behavior from the code, without any timing-related problems for the user to witness.

If the above seems a bit vague, it's only because your question does not include a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. If you'd like more specific advice, including a good code example showing exactly what the above options look like, please add a good code example to the question.

Comment: Thanks, I did think of extending the items to support the last checked time,  which would be a solid fix. Iit's just that I didn't want to clutter the class with UI related logic, as this set of items are used elsewhere in the application with no need for that functionality, and this seemed to be strictly a matter of UI.

Comment: As for the minimal example, I'd have to imitate SQL results with a fake item generator, thought the problem is clear enough, and you've understood the problem perfectly.

The rest of my view-model indeed does automatic notifications. It's only for this functionality that I wanted to make sure I notify the UI exactly when I want it to be: before I update the last checked time. Sorry for the language especially in my previous comment. Stack overflow doesn't let me correct those after 5 minutes :) (It shouldn't put a time limit if the comment is not viewed by anyone else, maybe)

Comment: _"that I wanted to make sure I notify the UI exactly when I want it to be"_ -- the right way to do that is to not update the property value until you want the UI notified. Leaving notification out for a property is just going to lead to hard-to-diagnose bugs down the road. _"I didn't want to clutter the class with UI related logic"_ -- a view model is by definition at least somewhat tied to the UI (hence "view" in the phrase). You can either accept the extra UI-specific member(s) or (as some people do) have a separate business logic model class which the view model references and delegates to.

Comment: All that said, if you really don't want to change the view model, then option #3 will work for you. The key is to bind to a property that is updated right away, is not changed until the next time the UI should reflect a change, and which stores not the most recent update time, but the next-to-most recent update time.

Comment: _"As for the minimal example, I'd have to imitate SQL results with a fake item generator"_ -- yes, in this scenario an [mcve] would necessarily include a sample data stream, complete with periodic updates. You wouldn't need to mock the entire SQL aspect; simply adding elements to a collection object periodically would suffice. If you feel the question is sufficiently answered without a code example, then there's no need for you to improve the code in your question. I just mention it in case you felt you would benefit from code in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Although, what I meant by "cluttering the class", I didn't mean the viewmodel, I meant the items that are being viewed, which I think belong to the model (I'd have to extend the items that are being viewed to add the 'LastCheckedTime' to the items themselves, just for the UI, but I may have understood you wrong), or do you mean I should convert each and every item to a class I specifically use for this specific view model?

I don't necessarily need a code, but pointing me to the general direction is enough. This discussion is already proving helpful as it is.

Comment: It's hard for me to offer specifics without starting with a specific code example. But, a flag on the view model should not require changes to the data model. In theory, you would simply configure the flag when new data is loaded, based on what data was already loaded; the flag could be set based either on a comparison between the data model objects (i.e. set the flag if for a loaded data model, that data model had not already been previously loaded), or on a comparison between the stored `LastCheckedTime` and the data model's `ResultDate` value (which you imply is there already).

Comment: But, again...option #3 requires no changes to the view model at all, so that should work fine if for some reason adding a flag to the view model doesn't seem useful in your case.